# Adding a modal of an image once clicked from a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to add an image modal into the below code.

It is supposed to be a drop down menu and when you click on an option in the  menu it should open as a modal image.The image is to not be resizable or moved, similar to a popup image but gives the option to close the window and stay on the same page.

Have added the modal in as CSS but it just shows on top of the text in the drop down, not when clicking on the text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
background-color: #c2d500;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #c2d500;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 250px;
height:720px;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
min-width: 250px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1><center>Frequently Asked Questions</center></h1>
<p><center> Select your question from the menu below:</center></p>

<center><div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Questions</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

    <a href="https://www.ecusolutions.com/SharedContent/images/FAQ/FAQ1.png"     target="_blank">What is the minimum and maximum amount for purchase?</a>
    <a href="https://www.ecusolutions.com/SharedContent/images/FAQ/FAQ2.png" target="_blank">Who may purchase ECU investment shares?</a>
    <a href="https://www.ecusolutions.com/SharedContent/images/FAQ/FAQ3.png" target="_blank">What type of investment accounts are available for ECU Investment shares?</a>
    <a href="https://www.ecusolutions.com/SharedContent/images/FAQ/FAQ4.png" target="_blank">Are ECU Investment Shares insured by DICO?</a>
    <a href="https://www.ecusolutions.com/SharedContent/images/FAQ/FAQ5.png" target="_blank">What type of investors should consider ECU Investment Shares?</a>
    <a href="https://www.ecusolutions.com/SharedContent/images/FAQ/FAQ6.png" target="_blank">How can I buy ECU Investment Shares?</a>
    <a href="https://www.ecusolutions.com/SharedContent/images/FAQ/FAQ7.png" target="_blank">How would I know the status of my order for purchase which is in a “waiting list”?</a>
    <a href="https://www.ecusolutions.com/SharedContent/images/FAQ/FAQ8.png" target="_blank">Is there a minimum term in ECU investment shares?</a>
    <a href="https://www.ecusolutions.com/SharedContent/images/FAQ/FAQ9.png" target="_blank">Will there be fees involved in ECU investment shares?</a>
    <a href="https://www.ecusolutions.com/SharedContent/images/FAQ/FAQ10.png" target="blank">When and how may I redeem my shares?</a>
    <a hreaf="https://www.ecusolutions.com/SharedContent/images/FAQ/FAQ11.png" target="_blank">If I have an ECU Non-Redeemable GIC (non-registered, TFSA or RRSP) at a special rate, but would like to transfer its funds to ECU Investment shares available, will I be able to do this?</a>

 </div></center>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>


</html>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Create an hidden div with an image and a closebutton. Replace in click of your link the src of the hidden image and show the hidden div. And Your Closebutton sets your div to hidden. I can debug your Code, but not wirte for you.